# Вывод json на страницу

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

Получаю json такого вида:

```
{
"200000006002":{"21473":{"IID":"200000006002","MED_ID":"21473","MED_NAME":"Камирен таб 4мг №30","VENDOR_NAME":"KRKA d.d. Novo Mesto","COUNTRY_NAME":"Словения","KIND_ID":"1","KIND_NAME":"Лекарственные средства","VENDORBARCODE":"3838989539887","RPRICE":"634,2","SRICEWNDS":"558,15","RATE":"14,99","PART_ID":"77001","DPRICE":"634,2","QTTY":"1","PREPAY_ENABLE":"0","INTER_ID":"1390","INTER_NAME":"Doxazosin","PHARM_ID":"7","PHARM_NAME":"Альфа-адреноблокаторы","IS_NARC":"0","TK_ID":"564000","TK_NAME":"Средства для лечения ДГПЖ","TKR_ID":"34000","TKR_NAME":"Урология. Нефрология. Андрология","VALID_DATE":"01.04.2022","NDS":"10" ,"GTD":"10013040/120717/0000259","MAX_OTP":"0"
}},
"200000037002":{"10001891":{"IID":"200000037002","MED_ID":"10001891","MED_NAME":"Перчатки полиэтил Пеха-Фол р.1 №100 д/женщин","VENDOR_NAME":"Paul Hartmann AG","COUNTRY_NAME":"Германия","KIND_ID":"7","KIND_NAME":"Изделия медицинского назначения","RPRICE":"184","SRICEWNDS":"152,93","RATE":"20,32","PART_ID":"152001","DPRICE":"184","QTTY":"1","PREPAY_ENABLE":"0","IS_NARC":"0","TK_ID":"538000","TK_NAME":"Перчатки резиновые и латексные","TKR_ID":"976000","TKR_NAME":"Санитарно-защитные изделия","VALID_DATE":"31.12.2020","NDS":"18" ,"GTD":"10013010/100717/0000405/1","BRAND_ID":"71001","BRAND_NAME":"ПаульХартманн","MAX_OTP":"0"
}},
"200000038002":{"10001877":{"IID":"200000038002","MED_ID":"10001877","MED_NAME":"Перчатки полиэтил Пеха-Фол р.2 №100 д/мужчин","VENDOR_NAME":"Paul Hartmann AG","COUNTRY_NAME":"Германия","KIND_ID":"7","KIND_NAME":"Изделия медицинского назначения","RPRICE":"184","SRICEWNDS":"152,93","RATE":"20,32","PART_ID":"152001","DPRICE":"184","QTTY":"1","PREPAY_ENABLE":"0","IS_NARC":"0","TK_ID":"538000","TK_NAME":"Перчатки резиновые и латексные","TKR_ID":"976000","TKR_NAME":"Санитарно-защитные изделия","VALID_DATE":"31.12.2020","NDS":"18" ,"GTD":"10130110/170816/0002902/1","BRAND_ID":"71001","BRAND_NAME":"ПаульХартманн","MAX_OTP":"0"
}}
}
```

И вот мой js:

```
var cart = {}; //моя корзина

function init() {
    //вычитываем файл goods.json
    $.getJSON("goods.json", goodsOut);
}

function goodsOut(data) {
    //вывод на страницу
    var out = '';
    for (var key in data) {
        out+='<tr class="cart_tovar">';
        out+='<td>';
        out+='<p class="tovar_name">'+data[key].MED_NAME+'</p>';
        out+='<p class="tovar_name_desc">'+data[key].description+'</p>';
        out+='</td>';
        out+='<td>';
        out+='<p class="tovar_manufacturer">'+data[key].VENDOR_NAME+'</p>';
        out+='<p class="tovar_country">'+data[key].COUNTRY_NAME+'</p>';
        out+='</td>';
        out+='<td class="tovar_cost">от '+data[key].RPRICE+' ₽</td>';
        out+='<td class="tovar_apteka">'+data[key].apteki+'</td>';
        out+='<td>';
        out+='<button class="add-to-cart" data-id="'+key+'">В корзину</button>';
        out+='</td>';
        out+='</tr>';
    }
    $('.goods-out').html(out);
    $('.add-to-cart').on('click', addToCart);
}

function addToCart() {
    //добавляем товар в корзину
    var id = $(this).attr('data-id');
    if (cart[id]!=undefined) {
        cart[id]++;
    }
    else {
        cart[id] = 1;
    }
    showMiniCart();
    saveCart();
}

function saveCart() {
    //сохраняю корзину в localStorage
    localStorage.setItem('cart', JSON.stringify(cart));
}

function showMiniCart(){
    //показываю содержимое корзины
    var out = Object.keys(cart).length;
    $('.mini-cart').html(out);
}

function loadCart() {
    //проверяю есть ли в localStorage запись car
    if (localStorage.getItem('cart')) {
        //если есть - расшифровываю и записываю в переменную cart
        cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('cart'));
        showMiniCart();
    }
}

$(document).ready(function () {
    init();
    loadCart();
});
```

Не могу понять, где ошибка, почему не выводит на страницу.

Answer (score 2):

При первом переборе, вы достаете объекты внутри которых еще объекты. То есть вам надо полученный объект снова перебрать, и уже из него выводить свойства. Для примерна на первой итерации вы получаете объект:

```
{
    21473:{
    ​COUNTRY_NAME: "Словения"
    ​​DPRICE: "634,2"
    ​​GTD: "10013040/120717/0000259"
    ​​IID: "200000006002"
    ​​INTER_ID: "1390"
    ​​INTER_NAME: "Doxazosin"
    ​​IS_NARC: "0"
    ​​KIND_ID: "1"
    ​​KIND_NAME: "Лекарственные средства"
    ​​MAX_OTP: "0"
    ​​MED_ID: "21473"
    ​​MED_NAME: "Камирен таб 4мг №30"
    ​​NDS: "10"
    ​​PART_ID: "77001"
    ​​PHARM_ID: "7"
    ​​PHARM_NAME: "Альфа-адреноблокаторы"
    ​​PREPAY_ENABLE: "0"
    ​​QTTY: "1"
    ​​RATE: "14,99"
    ​​RPRICE: "634,2"
    ​​SRICEWNDS: "558,15"
    ​​TKR_ID: "34000"
    ​​TKR_NAME: "Урология. Нефрология. Андрология"
    ​​TK_ID: "564000"
    ​​TK_NAME: "Средства для лечения ДГПЖ"
    ​​VALID_DATE: "01.04.2022"
    ​​VENDORBARCODE: "3838989539887"
    ​​VENDOR_NAME: "KRKA d.d. Novo Mesto"
    ​​}
}
```

И у этого объекта есть свойство `21473` и нет свойств `MED_NAME` и т.д. Вам необходимо зайти внутрь этого объекта, и тогда уже будет доступ к нужным вам свойствам.

```js
let data = { "200000006002":{"21473":{"IID":"200000006002","MED_ID":"21473","MED_NAME":"Камирен таб 4мг №30","VENDOR_NAME":"KRKA d.d. Novo Mesto","COUNTRY_NAME":"Словения","KIND_ID":"1","KIND_NAME":"Лекарственные средства","VENDORBARCODE":"3838989539887","RPRICE":"634,2","SRICEWNDS":"558,15","RATE":"14,99","PART_ID":"77001","DPRICE":"634,2","QTTY":"1","PREPAY_ENABLE":"0","INTER_ID":"1390","INTER_NAME":"Doxazosin","PHARM_ID":"7","PHARM_NAME":"Альфа-адреноблокаторы","IS_NARC":"0","TK_ID":"564000","TK_NAME":"Средства для лечения ДГПЖ","TKR_ID":"34000","TKR_NAME":"Урология. Нефрология. Андрология","VALID_DATE":"01.04.2022","NDS":"10" ,"GTD":"10013040/120717/0000259","MAX_OTP":"0" }}, "200000037002":{"10001891":{"IID":"200000037002","MED_ID":"10001891","MED_NAME":"Перчатки полиэтил Пеха-Фол р.1 №100 д/женщин","VENDOR_NAME":"Paul Hartmann AG","COUNTRY_NAME":"Германия","KIND_ID":"7","KIND_NAME":"Изделия медицинского назначения","RPRICE":"184","SRICEWNDS":"152,93","RATE":"20,32","PART_ID":"152001","DPRICE":"184","QTTY":"1","PREPAY_ENABLE":"0","IS_NARC":"0","TK_ID":"538000","TK_NAME":"Перчатки резиновые и латексные","TKR_ID":"976000","TKR_NAME":"Санитарно-защитные изделия","VALID_DATE":"31.12.2020","NDS":"18" ,"GTD":"10013010/100717/0000405/1","BRAND_ID":"71001","BRAND_NAME":"ПаульХартманн","MAX_OTP":"0" }}, "200000038002":{"10001877":{"IID":"200000038002","MED_ID":"10001877","MED_NAME":"Перчатки полиэтил Пеха-Фол р.2 №100 д/мужчин","VENDOR_NAME":"Paul Hartmann AG","COUNTRY_NAME":"Германия","KIND_ID":"7","KIND_NAME":"Изделия медицинского назначения","RPRICE":"184","SRICEWNDS":"152,93","RATE":"20,32","PART_ID":"152001","DPRICE":"184","QTTY":"1","PREPAY_ENABLE":"0","IS_NARC":"0","TK_ID":"538000","TK_NAME":"Перчатки резиновые и латексные","TKR_ID":"976000","TKR_NAME":"Санитарно-защитные изделия","VALID_DATE":"31.12.2020","NDS":"18" ,"GTD":"10130110/170816/0002902/1","BRAND_ID":"71001","BRAND_NAME":"ПаульХартманн","MAX_OTP":"0" }} }

function goodsOut(data) {
    //вывод на страницу
    var out = '';
    for (var key in data) {
      for(item in data[key]){
        out+='<tr class="cart_tovar">';
        out+='<td>';
        out+='<p class="tovar_name">'+data[key][item].MED_NAME+'</p>';
        out+='<p class="tovar_name_desc">'+data[key][item].TK_NAME+'</p>';
        out+='</td>';
        out+='<td>';
        out+='<p class="tovar_manufacturer">'+data[key][item].VENDOR_NAME+'</p>';
        out+='<p class="tovar_country">'+data[key][item].COUNTRY_NAME+'</p>';
        out+='</td>';
        out+='<td class="tovar_cost">от '+data[key][item].RPRICE+' ₽</td>';
        out+='<td class="tovar_apteka">'+data[key][item].apteki+'</td>';
        out+='<td>';
        out+='<button class="add-to-cart" data-id="'+data[key][item].BRAND_ID+'">В корзину</button>';
        out+='</td>';
        out+='</tr>';
    }
}
    $('.goods-out').html(out);
}

goodsOut(data);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class='goods-out'></div>
```

Comment: пробую вот так. но опять же не выводит

Comment: Что выводит? Что пишет? Если добавите полный код, чтоб можно было посмотреть, было бы супер.

Comment: просто полный код сюда добавить тяжело будет

Comment: внизу добавил код  - ответом

Comment: просто сюда я добавил выдержку из json, 3 товара,а всего их более 500

Comment: Надо смотреть на JSON который у вас, возможно там еще есть вложенности. Ну или полей нет с такими именами.

Comment: https://dropmefiles.com/buL4B

Comment: скинул его сюда, посмотрите

Comment: Проверил Ваш файл, все работает. Местами есть undefined, потому что поля такого нет. Но я же не знаю что вы там хотите выводить. Проверьте что это за поля, поправьте имена и все будет отображаться.

Comment: когда добавляю let data= "закидываю сюда значения из json". Все работает да, но ведь так нельзя. json лежит отдельным файлом, его вычитывать нужно

Comment: Да, это я просто добавил для того чтоб показать что оно работает. У меня то этого файла нет. Поэтому let data имитирует данные которые пришли.

Comment: я понимаю, вот в этом и проблема, что если делаю как вы указали, все работает, а если как у меня, вывода не происходит

Comment: Тогда надо смотреть на реализацию получения данных и как вы с ними работаете.

Comment: исправил json, нашел у вас ошибку в данной строке:

Comment: out+='<button class="add-to-cart" data-id="'+data[key][item].BRAND_ID+'">В корзину</button>';

Comment: Отлично, главное что заработало.